# C++ Struct attributes can change within function, but remain unchanged outside scope of function

Tags: c++11, struct, scope

I'm working on a self imposed challenge which involves implementing a linked list and an append function for it, which is giving me issues seemingly related to variable scope.

The append function loops through each link element until it reads a `NULL` value and then changes the data value associated with that link to the function input. The test outputs within the function seem to show it is working as intended, but when performing the same test outside the function, even after it is called gives a different output.

```
template <class T>
struct atom{
    T data;
    atom<T>* link = NULL;
};

template <class T>
void append_LL(atom<T> first, T input_data){

    atom<T>* current_node = &first;

    atom<T>* next_node = current_node->link;

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 4 && next_node != NULL) {
        current_node = next_node;
        next_node = next_node->link;
        i ++;
    }
    current_node->data = input_data;
    current_node->link = (atom<T>*)malloc(sizeof(atom<T>));
    cout << "leaving node as: " << current_node->data << endl; //outputs 5
    cout << "input nodes data: " << first.data << endl;        //outputs 5
}
int main() {

    int dd = 5;
    atom<int> linked_list;
    linked_list.data = 999;

    append_LL(linked_list, dd);

    cout << linked_list.data << endl; //outputs 999
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not sending the same `atom`. You see the program is making a copy of the `linked_list` in the `main` function and sending that copy to the function.

If you want to modify the same `linked_list` then change

```
void append_LL(atom<T> first, T input_data){
```

to

```
void append_LL(atom<T> &first, T input_data){
```

That way you are sending the really `atom` not a copy of it.

Comment: How does this not interfere with the type of first? Even when I add that to the argument I still have the address in `atom<T>* current_node = &first;` It seems like this would get the address of the address, but it works just fine. How does this work exactly?

Comment: You maybe want to do more reading on calling by reference in C++. It is a bit bigger than being able to explain it in a comment.